# Is it necessary to call dispose on winform controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Lets say I have a simple user control with one picturebox added from the code behind:

```
public partial class UserControlBase : UserControl
{
    public UserControlBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1280, 1048);

        // Logo
        PictureBox pbLogo = new PictureBox();
        pbLogo.Name = "pbLogo";
        pbLogo.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Logo;
        pbLogo.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        pbLogo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1280, 162);
        pbLogo.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;

        this.Controls.Add(pbLogo);
```

Would I have to override the dispose method on UserControlBase and call .dispose() on the picturebox?  Or would it eventually get cleaned up on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4zkb31d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Control.Dispose` takes care of all child controls:

> Releases the unmanaged resources used by the Control and its child controls and optionally releases the managed resources.

So, assuming the form containing the `UserControl` gets disposed, your `UserControl` and all its children will be disposed as well.

**Edit:** I should add that this is only true if your `UserControl` is still a child of the form when the form is disposed.  If you remove it from the control hierarchy, you're responsible for disposing of it yourself.  But even then, disposing of the `UserControl` will dispose of all its children.

Comment: I will manually call the dispose method on UserControlBase, so it looks like I'm good.